# How to tell Mifare Plus from others?

Tags: rfid, mifare

How would one determine what version of Mifare a system is using, if one only has access to the fob?

For example:
[https://www.amazon.com/MIFARE-Blue-Key-Fobs-RFID/dp/B011PJXG0U](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011PJXG0U)

From the product info this cheap blue fob can be used for any of the Mifare standards. What is the minimum equipment that one would need to discern the version and whether or not it is encrypted?

Comment: You are basically asking how to look up each RFID system to look up the specs. I think that answer to that is to simply visit the vendor's product pages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not specifically familiar with how the Plus works, but I can comment on the first two questions.

To identify a card, you can look at its SAK and, if applicable, its ATS. MIFARE card identification procedures are shown in [this document](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10834.pdf), on page 7. [This webpage](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php/ISO14443A) has some additional information.

To interact with the card, you'll need an NFC reader, such as an ACR122U, as well as libnfc. Libnfc's `nfc-list` command will print out some basic information about any cards it detects, including the SAK and ATS (if applicable) needed to identify the card. I also made my own tool to print out basic information about a card and roughly identify it, and you can see how that works [here](https://github.com/VortixDev/mfinfo/blob/master/src/mfinfo.c#L303).